# Not able to run Ubuntu touch in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-sdk

I created a first project. And tried to run the application. But it showed following error.

```
sent 960 bytes  received 106 bytes  2.13K bytes/sec <br/>
total size is 40.97K  speedup is 38.44 <br/>
20:10:22: The process "/usr/bin/rsync" exited normally. <br/>
WARNING:root:Ignoring missing framework "ubuntu-sdk-14.10-dev2" <br />
Successfully built package in './com.ubuntu.developer.username.untitled_0.1_all.click'. <br />

20:10:31: The process "/usr/bin/click" exited normally.

20:10:31: The click package has been created in /home/vp7/Ubuntu apps /build-untitled-
UbuntuSDK_for_i386_GCC_ubuntu_sdk_14_04_trusty-default

20:10:31: Deploy step failed. No valid device configured

Error while building/deploying project untitled (kit: UbuntuSDK for i386 (GCC ubuntu-sdk-14.04-trusty))

When executing step 'Upload files to Ubuntu Device'
20:10:32: Elapsed time: 00:11.
```

When I see list of devices running using `adb devices` the output was **emulator-5556   device**

for `uname -m` the output is **i686**

Comment: Open terminal and run your qml file using `qmlscene` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you associated your emulator with you kit?  To do this, go to *Tools > Options > Build & Run > Kits* and select your kit ("UbuntuSDK for i386 (GCC ubuntu-sdk-14.04-trusty)", judging from the error message.  Make sure "Device Type" is set to "Ubuntu Device (i386)".  Then select the correct emulator instance from the "Device" options.

Here are the options in question.  My emulator is named "aug11i386", but yours probably has another name.
[image: Screenshot of options page]

You can see all of your emulators in the *Devices* tab in Qt Creator.  Each lists which kit it is associated with.  If it's not associated with a kit, it offers to make a new kit for you, but oddly there doesn't seem to be a way to associate it with an existing kit here.  Instead, you have to go through the *Options* menu as descripted above.